# Angular form validation - get all validation errors

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I am looking for a solution for following problem:

I have a form like this:

```
<form (ngSubmit)="submit(f.form)" #f="ngForm">
  <label>Name</label>
  <input type="text" name="name" required />
  ...
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

I process it like this:

```
submit(f: FormGroup): void {
  Object.keys(form.controls).forEach(key => {

    const controlErrors: ValidationErrors = form.get(key).errors;
    if (controlErrors != null) {
      Object.keys(controlErrors).forEach(keyError => {
      console.log('Key control: ' + key + ', keyError: ' + keyError + ', err value: ', controlErrors[keyError]);
    });
  }
});
```

So I output to the console all the validation errors in a generic way. In this processing I need to be able to access value of a label which is next to the input to get its value instead of key. So I can make a message saying '{labelValue} is required.'. How can I access value of label. I cannot make it a ViewChild as I am looking for a generic solution and I cannot make a ViewChild for every label element in form.

Comment: label value is static y you need it. without any reference you cannot get the text

Comment: I have the feeling you're trying to reinvent ngx-valdemort. https://ngx-valdemort.ninja-squad.com/#/

Comment: Try accessing the native element from the form control. It might help.